# SpringSocialConfigurer with rememberMe causing java.lang.IllegalStateException: securityBuilder cannot be null

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social

I have my spring social configuration

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/secured/**").authenticated()

    .and()
        .formLogin()

    .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")

    .and()
        .httpBasic()

    .and()
        .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer())
```

At this point all work great, but when I try to add rememberMe() it ends up with

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: securityBuilder cannot be null
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter.getBuilder(SecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:65)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter.and(SecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter$and.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at my.super.package.SecurityConfigurer.configure(SecurityConfigurer.groovy:89)
```

Comment: Where is this *rememberMe()* declared? Cmon ppl here are not God.

Comment: rememberMe is method of HttpSecurity class with is java config security builder: [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.java#L550)